# Java connection to remote MySql-database succeeds from 1 ip-address only. Why?

Tags: mysql

I built a local application that uses data from a remote database. It works beautifully from two different machines, but *only* from 1 IP-address (my own). If I try to connect elsewhere or via mobile internet, I get this error:

jdbc.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

So, for clarity: it is not:
1. the code, that works. 
2  the machine, it works on at least 2 machines, a desktop and a laptop.
3. the operating system, the desktop uses Windows 7, the laptop Winsows 10.
4. things like a firewall, I tried, it makes no difference

I built the thing using netbeans 8.2. It does not make a difference whether I run the application from within it or straight from the jar.

The only differende I can see is the address from which I enter the net. And that should not make a diffrence. I'm at a loss here, so please help.

Comment: What does it means "from 1 address", do you mean only inside your local network?

Comment: No. Like I said, the program works with remote databases on any machine, but only when accessing the internet through my home wifi router. This means: if I connect my own laptop through my own router, things work without a hitch. If I take that laptop to the corner café and use its wifi, it can't connect, nor anywhere else. And there's no problem with internet access, everything else works like clockwork.

Comment: That's what I meant. It's possible that you are blocked from accessing public networks, but private networks are fine. This may be a setting of the firewall. Check in `Windows Defender Firewall` (not `Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security`)  what are the settings for "Guest or public networks". To change settings, click "Turn Windows Defender Firewall on or off".

Comment: Sorry, that won't help either. One of the first things I tried was shutting down everything, firewall and antivirus. didn't make a difference.
In fact, I let the same machine on the same table at appr. the same time connect through my standard router (works fine) and through an internet stick, and guess what: it can't make the connection.
Btw: the internet stick is okay, it connects to everywhere else on the internet.